# Can't drag button action to existing function in Xcode 8

Tags: swift, xcode, drag-and-drop, storyboard, interface-builder

I have a weird issue with Xcode 8. When I try to ctrl + drag button to existing function, I can't I can only create new outlet or Action. What is more weird, that even when I create action by ctrl + drag i can't connect event the same button that I used for creating action. IB icon is also blank like there is no connection between action and button, but real time clicking runs action.
On the other hand when I try to connect action to button from swift to storyboard I can (@IB icon becomes "full"), but then I get exception on real time clicking unrecognized selector myActionWithSender
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To fix it, I had to update my project language to Swift 3.0 from Swift 2.3

Answer (score 22):

In my Xcode version, IBAction is created automatically with "Any" parameter, instead of "AnyObject". Creating IBAction explicitly with UIButton instead worked for me.

Comment: This was my solution as well.  You can also manually change Any to AnyObject it the existing code and it works as advertised.  Why does Xcode default to Any?  Thanks for this solution!

Answer (score 12):

In my case, you will need to change Any to UIButton. It need to be specific that the action coming from UIButton.

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Click on the UIButton, then go to "Connections Inspector" from Utilities area.

Click on the empty circle beside the event and drag the line into func body.

Answer (score 0):

In your .swift file change:

`@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    // Do something
}`

to

`@IBAction func buttonClicked(z sender: UIButton) {
    // Do something
}`

Just add that little 'z' (or whatever label you want really). I tried an underscore '_', and that works as well, but it gives a warning, so I just used a 'z' instead to get around the warning.

I believe it's a bug in Xcode 8. Somewhere (IB probably) it's expecting Swift 3 compliant code where the first parameter MUST have a label. So when it sees the word "sender" it assumes (wrongly) that that's the label.  So adding a label ('z' in my case) makes everybody happy.

Swift 2.3 does not require a label. Swift 3 does. So, as Jaroslaw pointed out upgrading from 2.3 to 3.0 will also get around this problem. But if you're project is stuck on 2.3, just adding a label seems to do the trick.

Comment: Strange observance: if I use an underscore '_' I can drag from IB to the function name in code, and it highlights the entire function - and it makes the connection.  However, if I use 'z' or any other alphanumeric label, I cannot drag from IB to the function name.  Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Change sender from Any to AnyObject works for me

Answer (score 0):

Even in Swift 3, you'd like to change the `@IBAction`'s argument from `(_ sender: Any)` to `(_ sender: UIButton)` or (`_ sender: AnyObject)`, but manually.

It might work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was had a similar storyboard open. Once I closed it and then 
- clicked the button once to see the blocks around it for alignment.
- Then right clicked and dragged it to the ViewController.
- Lastly, click/tap where you want to place the event's code block inside the ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Right click with open button function in select touchup inside to drag.